# Linux C Standard I/O - why double copying

Tags: c, linux, glibc, system-calls

Assuming I understand the flow correctly, one would like to read few byes off an opened `FILE` stream, lets says, using `fread`:

1. the `read` syscall will copy the data from the kernel to the user space buffer
2. user space buffer (either allocated by *glibc* or provided by `setvbuf`...) will be copied to the buffer provided to `fread`

why is the 2nd step needed? why can I get a pointer to the user space buffer which I will decide if I want to store (copy) or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the 2nd buffer is to amortize the system call overhead. If you read/write only a few bytes at a time, this second user space buffer will improve performance enormously. OTOH if you read/write a large chunk, the 2nd buffer can be bypassed, so you don't pay the price for double copying.

Answer (score -1):

The second step is what it is all about. Kernel must take care of such operations. The api you use will be feeded  afterwards with the result. This is usual kernelspace/user space behaviour. Read about it. You perhaps might not know it NOW but kernel space/ user space differentiation are basics of os infrastructure.

Comment: -1 This does nothing to actually answer the question of what purpose the standard library's intermediate buffer serves.